# Difference between make 'an' effort and make 'the' effort

Tags: word-choice, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, determiners

Consider the following sentence.

> Yet I still enjoy making ____ (an/the) effort to bake at home from time to time.

Here, what is the difference between an and the? Is effort here a specific or common noun?

Comment: What does basic research show? Macmillan states that they are variants with the same meaning. Google data somewhat disconcertingly has 30 200 000 hits for each! // 'An' is licensed by 'effort' not having being mentioned so far, while 'the' is licensed by post-specification (the Lord of the Rings, the back of beyond, the effort to bake at home).

Comment: ok @EdwinAshworth, but as per the textbook I'm referring to, the answer is specified as "the". There is no previous mention of the word "effort" at all. Although, even I do agree with you, I just wanted to make it sure

Comment: With the, it's clear what's involved—something specific (baking at home). *An* to me means *any* or *some*-- *you didn't make an/any effort* = took no steps. *You should make the effort of driving to see her. You should make an effort—drive to see her, call her, send her a letter.* Have a look at specific instances of use and see if you perceive a difference.

Comment: My impression is that you _make an effort_ in general terms (someone watching you do a manual task without much enthusiasm says "Come on! Make an effort!"), but you _make the effort_ to do a particular task (motivate yourself, prepare the equipment etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt OP's cited speaker "literally" enjoys ***making a/the effort*** to do home baking. More likely she enjoys the ***process*** of baking (disregarding the "effort"), and/or the subsequent eating or offering to others of the fruits of her labours.

This kind of "loose" phrasing is quite normal in English, and most Anglophones would say my observation is pedantic / over-exacting. I only make the point because to speakers of some other languages, the phrasing *may* seem odd.

---

Having said all that, I think a slightly different example sentence better shows how different articles can affect meaning...

> 1: *I make **the** effort to clean my teeth twice a day*  - I *do* it, but it's an effort
> 2: *I make **an** effort to clean my teeth twice a day*  - I *try* to do it, *perhaps* successfully

Many if not most native speakers would agree it's *unambiguous* that that the speaker in #1 *does in fact* clean his teeth twice daily - but that's ***not*** true for #2 (where although the speaker *tries* to achieve his goal, it's implied that he's not always successful). Bear in mind this is quite a fine difference, that won't always be either intended by a speaker, or understood by his audience.

I could perhaps justify this difference on the grounds that #1 refers to *a specific amount of effort* (the amount needed to *achieve* the goal), whereas #2 simply implies *some* effort (but possibly not enough to succeed).